# What is the meaning of "will fulfill a prophecy by bringing balance to the Force"?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/synopsis)

> Qui-Gon senses a strong presence of the Force in Anakin, and feels
>   that he may be the "Chosen One" an individual the Jedi believe **will
>   fulfill a prophecy by bringing balance to the Force.**

My understanding:
Prophecy means "a prediction of what will happen in the future."
Prophecy itself means prediction. What does the author mean when he says "fulfill a prediction?"

In "by bringing balance to the Force," 
what does "Force" mean and how does it relate to prophecy?

Small question: In the this clause in the above sentence: **the Jedi believe will fulfill a prophecy** — who is believing whom ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [SE: Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [SE: Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1: What does the author mean when he says "fulfill a prediction?"

A prophecy is fulfilled when whatever is predicted to happen, happens.

A person can fulfil a prophecy by causing the thing to happen.  If a prophecy says that a person will be born, then someone can fulfil the prophecy by being that person.

For example, Christians believe that the birth of Jesus fulfils many prophecies from the Old Testament.

In this case, the prophecy says that someone will bring balance to the force.  Qui-Gon believes that Anakin will bring balance to the force.  If he does, then he will have caused the thing to happen, and therefore fulfilled the prophecy.

> Q2: what does "Force" mean and how does it relate to prophecy?

The 'Force' in the prophecy only has a meaning within the context of Star Wars, where it means a spiritual energy used by the Jedi and the Sith.  If you want to know more about that subject it's better to ask on [Science Fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).

> Q3: In the this clause in the above sentence: the Jedi believe will
>   fulfill a prophecy — who is believing whom ?

The Jedi are believing that the individual will fulfil the prophecy.  They are believing a statement, not a person.